# set strictQuery to false on a find method level

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Mongoose 6 introduced many changes, and the most important change was the `strict` and `strictQuery` for the search queries, they are equal to true by default.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#strictquery-is-removed-and-replaced-by-strict

I have a schema like this:

```js
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
})
```

And I have a document like the following in the database:

```js
{
   name: "Murat",
   _archived: true
}
```

as You can see, the field `_archived` does not exist in the schema.

Now If I wanted to:

```js
const archivedDocs = await myModel.find({ _archived: true })
```

I can't because of the new update.

Mongoose says that if you wanted to perform this search query, you can add the `strictQuery` option to your schema and set it to true.

However, I don't want to do that, because this will have an effect everywhere. I only want to allow this one **find()** line of code to pass this checking.

Is there something in mongoose that I can do like:

```js
const archivedDocs = await myModel.find({ _archived: true }, { strictQuery: false })
```

??

Comment: Important: I have noticed that doing so on `find()` does not work, but works when using `findOne()`, **and** the way I am using it above is wrong, it must be:  `const archivedDocs = await myModel.findOne({ _archived: true }, null,  { strictQuery: false })`   
-----   
   Now we know that it works for `findOne()`,  is this option available for the `find()` method, and if not then why, and what workarounds do we have

Answer (score 3):

Yes the same "workaround" for the `findOne` will work for the `find` method.

they both receive the same options in the same order: `filter`, `projection` then `options`. So when you provide `options = { strictQuery: false }` to the `findOne` method it works. the same exact syntax will work for the `find`, like so:

```
const archivedDocs = await myModel.find({ _archived: true }, null, { strictQuery: false })
```

Comment: For some reason it's only working for `findOne()` not `find()` with me. Maybe because I'm calling it like `this.find()` inside a `pre(/^find/)` middleware? anyway, thanks, I'm okay with the findOne at the moment. but maybe someone else reading my question will benefit from your post in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, that's a "different" find method, you can use `this.model.find` instead of `this.find` within the "pre" function to use the proper one.

Comment:  hmm... that's weird. but `this.model.find` did not work as well

Comment: although, what does the `strictQuery` does?